# Animation in error panel for UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I would like to create a error bar like the Mail app of Windows 10.
It shows the error and few seconds later, it is hidden with an animation that move the panel to the edge.

I suspect that I could use EdgeUIThemeTransition or PaneThemeTransition  but I am not clear how to use it. The image show the error panel (red color). Is must be a StackPanel? a Popup? ...

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one specifically, do you have a video or something showing the exact behavior? I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably made by creating custom Panel (Grid / StackPanel ...), injected into the view by xaml or code behind. The animation can be easily created manually by code.

Use DoubleAnimation to animate the TranslateX of the Transfomer of the panel for example.